# How to dynamically find the IP address of a specific device in a small network?

Tags: android, networking, ip, esp8266

I am developing a small-scale hobby project which involves an Android app and an ESP8266. The basic idea is, the ESP8266 will control an RGB led and the app will let me do this control remotely.

In my architecture, the ESP8266 will be connected to my home network and when my smartphone is connected to the same network, when I open the app the phone and the ESP8266 will pair and I will do the control over wifi. But the IP address of the ESP will change dynamically. My question is, how can I find out the IP address of the ESP8266 if it's not static?

Comment: Please first tell what kind of server is running on your esp. Also used port.

Comment: It is a TCP socket server and port is 2806.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607795/esp8266-mdns-not-getting-discovered-in-andriod

Comment: This is what multicast was designed to do. Have your device listen on a particular multicast group, and your phone can send a message to the multicast group, then the device will respond via unicast to your phone. You phone will then have the unicast address of the device. In general, you want to use a multicast group in the `239.0.0.0/8` range.

Comment: broadcast your IP via BLE or Ad-Hoc wifi until it is found and a connection is established

Comment: @Sam, broadcasting is a rookie move that will interrupt _every_ host on a LAN. Multicast is preferred because it only interrupts the hosts that are interested and listening on the multicast group.

Comment: Hi @RonMaupin please read my response accurately before making a statement about it's  "rookie" status. I specifically said "BLE or Ad-Hoc" wifi. To explain a bit since you apparently don't know the difference, Ad-Hoc wif is a stand alone wifi where multiple phones can broadcast and communicate via their wifi card to other nearby devices, Establishing their own stand alone connection without any other LAN equipment and wouldn't impact anything. BLE is also a stand alone broadcast technology that does not rely on LAN, but I appreciate you attempting to call out my answer in a "rookie way" haha.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html here is a link to help explain ad-hoc wifi or direct wifi, or Peer to Peer, whatever you prefer to call it.

Comment: @Ron Maupin actually this is kind of what I was looking for. I will go for multicast dns since I also found out that mongoose-os for esp8266 supports this natively. Thanks for all the other answers, they are all valuable. Please enter this as an answer also, so I can mark this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what multicast was designed to do. Have your device listen on a particular multicast group, and your phone can send a message to the multicast group, then the device will respond via unicast to your phone. You phone will then have the unicast address of the device. In general, you want to use a multicast group in the Organization-Local Scope (`239.0.0.0/8`) range.

Answer (score 1):

Just try them all.

On the Android device you first determine the ip of the device itself.

Say its `192.168.1.5`.

You will then know that the ip of the esp is like that. Like `192.168.1.xx`.

So just make a loop where you start with 192.168.1.3 and try to connect to it using your port. Set timeout to one second. If it times out try the next ip. Skip your own ip.

You will be amazed how quick the esp is found.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if I cannot find a better solution I will use this. By "better" I mean, more elegant programmatically.

Comment: There are 'better/or official solutions` but not as 'elegant' as this one ;-).